# Git: Fork GitHub Repo into different Repo

Tags: git, github, git-fork

### Original Question

This is the Git repository that I have at the moment, which is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/nchpmn/noto):

```
master
  railstut
```

I'm looking at customising Cloudhead's [toto](https://github.com/cloudhead/toto/) rails backend within this project.

The methodology I can think of for this would be to `fork` the project, but put it within a branch of my `noto` repository:

```
master
  railstut
  toto
```

The reason I want to do this is because for this repo, each branch is a different method of me trying to get a working backend for a blog. The reason I want branches and not different repositories for each attempt is to keep everything contained and neat.

So... is there any way to do this without downloading Cloudhead's repo, unzipping it to the working directory and committing it? Googling it hasn't helped, but that could easily be because I'm searching the wrong commands (mainly `fork`, `branch/checkout` and `clone`)

Questions to clarify are most welcome!

---

### Updates

**2012-07-03 @ 1053 AEST**

Bonus points if I can still make `pull` requests for bug fixes or updates. Though, this sounds a little pointless, given I'm customising and not patching, as forks are intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a remote name Cloudhead.

use this

```
git remote add cloudhead git@github.com:cloudhead/toto.git
```

then you can pull using the command:

```
git pull cloudhead master
```

Comment: And of course this to create your editable branch `git checkout -b toto cloudhead/master`

Comment: Exactly. I think that's all he need.